# Is it ok to store id's in the jwt?

Tags: jwt

I'm a little confused right now. I thought a jwt was, so we can easily authenticate users without making a DB call. I use the id's (user/organization) stored in the jwt for permissions etc.

But now i've read somewhere that you shouldn't store (almost) nothing in your jwt payload? If that's the case, why should i use a jwt?

I use a refresh token to refresh the authorization token every minute.

Example payload:

```
{
    "id": "user_id",
    "email": "user_email",
    "role": "user_role",
    "organization_account_id": "organization_account_id",
    "organization_id": "organization_id"
}
```

This way i can easily check permissions/fetch data with the right id's without making an extra DB (or cache) call.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot about JWT during the past decade, even create my own library for computing/verifying them. When I read "why should i use a jwt?" my first answer is that maybe you do not need it at all.

Mots of the time, their use is decided to authenticate users without DB call. But what is the benefits? When done correctly (index, good IDs...), a SGDB call takes less than 1ms. JWT verification takes almost the same time (signature verification+header/claims check) and, unless you have billions requests/sec to manage, you won't see any changes.

You may be interested in this blog post: https://jolicode.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-jwt

Now to answer your question "Is it ok to store id's in the jwt?".
The answer is YES. You can store any relevant data in the JWT payload. It should be adapted to your application needs and the context. IDs are fine because they are usually small  and do not contain sensitive information.